# How to set maximum time to lock?

Tags: android

I'm trying to set the maximum time to lock with `DevicePolicyManager.setMaximumTimeToLock()`, but this seems to have no effect. Admin-mode is enabled and `lockNow()` works without a problem. 
Is there anything else that needs to be done to use `setMaximumTimeToLock()` ?

tgr

Comment: Care to explain what you are trying to accomplish with your app? Then people can answer your question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Are trying to keep your screen from going off? Use this in your onCreate. I believe it has to go before calling setContentView.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: I'm trying to set the time to lock based on my location. I.e. when at home I want to lock the screen after 60 min, at work after 20 min and so on. I don't want to keep the screen from turning off, I just want to avoid unlocking it (typing my password) to often